# UITableView - Section header's disclosure button changes randomly

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to make my own table view displaying hierarchical data based on Apple's "Table View Animations and Gestures" sample code. 
Everything works fine in Apple's demo, until I add more root items than it is displayable on the screen.

Problem is that if I expand first root item and scroll down, the disclosure button of last root item displays expanded state. 
Then if I scroll to the top (sometimes it needs to be repeated few times), the disclosure button of first item already shows collapsed state but the item is still expanded. 
If I click to such item the app crashes with error:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'

I have copied the sample code from here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/tableviewupdates/TableViewUpdates.zip

Data source is "PlaysAndQuotations.plist" and it has been changed following:
Copy all 3 root dict items (also with their array of dicts) 4 times, so it contains 12 root items with all their subitems.

My adapted Plist data file can be downloaded here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B__nLmZ1h_-eUHVlTV9FbzN2aGc/edit?usp=sharing

Please help me to find out, why is the disclosure button changing its state by itself and  how to fix the crashes.

Answer (score 1):

This has solved the issue

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  Add the following :

  ```
  if (section == self.openSectionIndex ){
      sectionHeaderView.disclosureButton.selected = YES;
  }
  else
      sectionHeaderView.disclosureButton.selected = NO;
  ```

APLSectionHeaderView
- (void)toggleOpenWithUserAction:(BOOL)userAction {

```
// Comment this line self.disclosureButton.selected = !self.disclosureButton.selected; 
if (userAction) {
    // toggle the disclosure button state
    self.disclosureButton.selected = !self.disclosureButton.selected; //Add here
```